# JULIA 1.6.4 ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'OpenSpecFun'

Tags: package, julia

I am trying to add the package "Distributions" (and others):

```
(@v1.6) pkg> add Distributions
```

And I get:

```
ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'OpenSpecFun' from 'C:\Users\cescalac\.julia\packages\OpenSpecFun_jll\1Zaof\Artifacts.toml'
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:33
  [2] ensure_artifact_installed(name::String, meta::Dict{String, Any}, artifacts_toml::String; platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool, io::Base.TTY)
    @ Pkg.Artifacts C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Artifacts.jl:445
  [3] ensure_all_artifacts_installed(artifacts_toml::String; platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, pkg_uuid::Nothing, include_lazy::Bool, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool, io::Base.TTY)
    @ Pkg.Artifacts C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Artifacts.jl:510
  [4] download_artifacts(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkg_roots::Vector{String}; platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, verbose::Bool, io::Base.TTY)
    @ Pkg.Operations C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:710
  [5] download_artifacts(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, julia_version::VersionNumber, verbose::Bool, io::Base.TTY)
    @ Pkg.Operations C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:687
  [6] add(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, new_git::Vector{Base.UUID}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform)
    @ Pkg.Operations C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1242
  [7] add(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol, Base.TTY, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:io,), Tuple{Base.TTY}}})
    @ Pkg.API C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:204
  [8] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; io::Base.TTY, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Pkg.API C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:80
  [9] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})
    @ Pkg.API C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:78
 [10] #add#23
    @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:76 [inlined]
 [11] add
    @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:76 [inlined]
 [12] #add#22
    @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:75 [inlined]
 [13] add(pkg::String)
    @ Pkg.API C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:75
 [14] top-level scope
    @ REPL[1]:1
```

I uninstall everything, install again. The error persists. Thank you in advance if you can help me with the solution. Julia version 1.6.4.

With `ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"]="all"`, I get

```
julia> Pkg.add("Distributions")
   Resolving package versions...
 Downloading artifact: OpenSpecFun
┌ Debug: download_artifact error
│   tree_hash = SHA1("3e683ec5ca945a5aca74c49e8cccdf37c19b84a3")
│   tarball_url = "https://pkg.julialang.org/artifact/3e683ec5ca945a5aca74c49e8cccdf37c19b84a3"
│   tarball_hash = nothing
│   err = HTTP/1.1 403 MediaTypeBlocked while requesting https://pkg.julialang.org/artifact/3e683ec5ca945a5aca74c49e8cccdf37c19b84a3
  Downloaded artifact: OpenSpecFun
 Downloading artifact: OpenSpecFun
┌ Debug: download_artifact error
│   tree_hash = SHA1("3e683ec5ca945a5aca74c49e8cccdf37c19b84a3")
│   tarball_url = "https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/OpenSpecFun_jll.jl/releases/download/OpenSpecFun-v0.5.5+0/OpenSpecFun.v0.5.5.x86_64-w64-mingw32-libgfortran5.tar.gz"
│   tarball_hash = "56018ef016338b838d407cd58ffb7033584dd78c31b9d1082cdae10556a902cd"
│   err = HTTP/1.1 403 MediaTypeBlocked while requesting https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/OpenSpecFun_jll.jl/releases/download/OpenSpecFun-v0.5.5+0/OpenSpecFun.v0.5.5.x86_64-w64-mingw32-libgfortran5.tar.gz
  Downloaded artifact: OpenSpecFun
```

Comment: Can you post the full series of errors?

Comment: Thank you, Milan Bouchet-Valat. I edited the original query in response to your question.

Comment: Could you set `ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"]="all"` and then try again? There might be a lot of output, we're looking for lines with `download_artifact error` in them, which should give us more details about the error.

Comment: Thank you, @sundar-Remember Monica. I followed your advice. The problem persists. I wrote the result at the bottom of the original query using edit. I don't know how to do it another way.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 403 MediaTypeBlocked` Hmmm, sounds like a firewall/proxy on your computer or network that's blocking the download. Can you try the `pkg.julialang.org/...` address or the github one in your browser or with `wget` and see if you're able to do it? I'm guessing that'll be a 403 error too, in which case you'll have to check your firewall/proxy configuration and change it to allow this.

Comment: Thank you, sundar - Remember Monica. I will ask for local support to follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

*(pasting my comments as an answer since this seems likely to be the issue.)*

The output of `ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"]="all"` (which makes Artifacts print more detailed errors) indicates that it's a problem with downloading the artifact file.

```
│   err = HTTP/1.1 403 MediaTypeBlocked while requesting https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/OpenSpecFun_jll.jl/releases/download/OpenSpecFun-v0.5.5+0/OpenSpecFun.v0.5.5.x86_64-w64-mingw32-libgfortran5.tar.gz
```

`MediaTypeBlocked` in this case (since the link works for the rest of us) indicates that this is likely a firewall/proxy in your network that's blocking these files from being downloaded. You'll likely encounter the same error with any attempt to access these files, for eg. from a browser or with `wget`.

Changing the network config to allow these files would be the best course of action (and disallowing `tar.gz` files seems overly restrictive anyway). In case you're not able to do that, you can download the file from a different network and copy it to the place the artifacts mechanism would have placed it in, which would also allow this package installation to continue.